# Recursive array map from multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I need to build a map of all possibilities from multidimentional array in the following format:

```
$level['A1']['E1'] = true;
$level['E1']['A1'] = true;
$level['A1']['L1'] = true;
$level['L1']['A1'] = true;
$level['A1']['E2'] = true;
$level['E2']['A1'] = true;
$level['E1']['L1'] = true;
$level['L1']['E1'] = true;
$level['E1']['E2'] = true;
$level['E2']['E1'] = true;
```

Result needs to have all possible maps in another multidimentional array from A1 to A1, such as:

```
$level_maps['A1']['E1']['L1']['A1'] = true;
$level_maps['A1']['E1']['E2']['A1'] = true;
$level_maps['A1']['L1']['E1']['A1'] = true;
$level_maps['A1']['L1']['E1']['E2']['A1'] = true;
$level_maps['A1']['E2']['E1']['A1'] = true;
$level_maps['A1']['E2']['E1']['L1']['A1'] = true;
```

Initial array can be much bigger and I'm having a hard time with a recursive function.

Edit:

I have a simple class with the following function:

```
private function buildMap(array $levels, $parent) {
    $map = array();
    foreach ($levels as $level1 => $level2_vals) {
        foreach($level2_vals as $level2 => $val) {
            if ($parent == $level1) {
                $map[$level2] = true;
                unset($levels[$level1][$level2]);
                $level3 = $this->buildMap($levels, $level2);
                if(!empty($level3)  && $level2 != $this->end_level) {
                    $map[$level2] = $level3;
                }
                else if($level2 != $this->end_level) {
                    $map[$level2] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $map;
}
```

calling it with:

```
$map[$this->start_level] = $this->buildMap($level, $this->start_level);
```

but it does not work correctly, especially on bigger sets of levels.
Sorry if I am unclear, was just looking for a recursive function example to start with.

Comment: I for one can't work out the rules your using to generate your example, I'm guessing it's an incomplete example? Could you provide a full example with a smaller subset of the initial array? Why do some 4 dimensions and some 5?. And are values always going to be `true`?

Comment: Yes, it is incomplete - need to have all possible ways to get from A1 to A1 in parent-child relationship. The most simple result sets would include: $level_maps['A1']['E1']['A1'] = true; $level_maps['A1']['L1']['A1'] = true; etc.

Comment: But in your example you'd hit an infinite loop ? A1 -> E1 -> L1 -> A1 ->E1 -> L1 -> A1 etc etc. So I think we need more info. Also, you should provide the attempt you have made and what went wrong with it otherwise this is just a theoretical exercise.

Comment: We can assume that the result will always be true. In the initial set some levels may be not available and have something like $level['E2']['D1'] = false; but we can assume that they are all true in this case. As for level maps - I have a recursive function that sets the result elements to false if they don't end up with the initial A1 after going trough all possibilities.

Comment: Yes, infinite loop is a possibility, therefore unset of the used array elements during each result recursion is required.

Comment: If it is too much for a function, I would appreciate a link or idea for a simple class.

Comment: We don't do recommendations, search for things for you, nor do your work for you. We're happy to help with specific programming issues, but without you providing your code and a clear description of what works / doesn't work, errors, where you're stuck etc. there's nothing we can help with.

Comment: I added my initial function that does not work, was hoping to get an idea on making it better and getting a different idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here how it work check the example bellow :

```
<?php

$level['A1']['E1'] = true;
$level['E1']['A1'] = true;
$level['A1']['L1'] = true;
$level['L1']['A1'] = true;
$level['A1']['E2'] = true;
$level['E2']['A1'] = true;
$level['E1']['L1'] = true;
$level['L1']['E1'] = true;
$level['E1']['E2'] = true;
$level['E2']['E1'] = true;


/// generate array key 
$array_keys=array();
foreach($level as $key1 =>$values)
{
    foreach($values as $key2 => $values2)
    {
        $array_keys[]=$key1.'-'.$key2;

    }

}


/// split array parent and childrent on diffrent parts
$parent='A1';
$parent_keys=array();
$children_keys=array();
foreach($level as $key =>$val)
{


    foreach($val as $key2 =>$val2)
    {
        if($key == $parent)
        $parent_keys[$key.'-'.$key2]=true;
        else
            $children_keys[$key.'-'.$key2]=true;


    }




}

$last_array=array();
foreach($parent_keys as $key =>$va)
{

    $exp=explode('-',$key);


    foreach($children_keys as $key2 =>$va2)
    {
            $arrunique=array();
        if(!strchr($key2,$exp[1])){
        $exp2=explode('-',$key2);

        foreach($exp as $r)
        {
            $arrunique[$r]=$r;

        }

        foreach($exp2 as $r)
        {
            $arrunique[$r]=$r;

        }
        if(in_array($exp[1].'-'.$exp2[0],$array_keys))
        $last_array[implode('-',$arrunique).'-'.$exp[0]]=true;


        }


    }



}

foreach($last_array as $key=>$va)
{

    print $key."\n";


}
```

You can execute from sandbox : [LINK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1025a17ab32e9bd2577c2be01a48059a3c98eed1)

Comment: Thank you. Close, but it needs to be a recursive function as it may have more values and can be more than 3 foreach loop deep.